# How to save user added value from dialogue to room database in Android studio uding kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I am trying to add data from dialogue to user but it's not happening new item is blank

```
        binding.btnQuizfab.setOnClickListener { 
             var dialog=Dialog(mainActivity) 
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_question) 
             var etNewquestion=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etNewquestion) 
             var etOptionA=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etOptionA) 
             var etOptionB=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etOptionB) 
             var etOptionC=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etOptionC) 
             var etOptionD=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etOptionD) 
             var etOptioncorrect=dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etOptioncorrect) 
             dialog.dismiss() 
             dialog.show() 
             var name=etNewquestion.text.toString() 

             class insertQuestion : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() { 
                 override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? { 
                     var qquizDataClass = QuizDataClass(question = name , option_a = "$etOptionA", option_b = "$etOptionB", option_c = "$etOptionC", option_d = "$etOptionD", correct_option = "$etOptioncorrect") 
                     quizDatabase.quizDao().insertIntoQuiz(qquizDataClass) 
                     return null 
                 } 
                 override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) { 
                     super.onPostExecute(result) 
                     getQuizData() 
                 } 
             } 
             insertQuestion().execute() 
         } 
  
  
  
         return (binding.root) 
  
     }
```

I tried using getText() or text but none of them worked